# IIS AppPool administrator

Tags: iis-7

How can I make my IIS APPPool\NameHere administrator? I want my application to be able to check system processes to monitor Processes like **w3wp.exe** via the AppPool (C#)

It only allows me to get the name of the AppPool the application is currently running

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you will not be able to set AppPoolIdentity to a specific group, but you can

1. create a local user (compmgmt.msc)
2. add the user to the administrator group (compmgmt.msc)
3. Set the application pool to run under that user, under Advanced Settings.

Obviously you know this is a very bad idea from a security perspective, and should never ever ever be performed on a forward facing server.

You can assign permissions to an app pool user, even if you can't set them to a role. see instructions here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/81165/how-to-assign-permissions-to-applicationpoolidentity-account